# Incorrect CASE SQL statement

Tags: sql, oracle, case, where-clause

I've written an SQL statement that is giving me back invalid character. I know its to do with the case statement in my where so can anyone tell me the error. Thanks.

```
    WHERE
    <if test="gNumber != null">
        dph.GNUMBER = #{gNumber}
    </if>
    <if test="licence != null">
        dph.dlicenceNumber = #{licence}
    </if>
    AND dph.REASON = (CASE WHEN dph.REASON IS NOT NULL THEN par.CODE END)
```

Comment: Is this mark up allowed in SQL syntax? I do not think so...

Comment: I'm trying to do an if within the where, making sure that REASON is not null @Michak Turczyn

Comment: But such syntax is not supported in SQL. It generates error

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results, and a clear explanation of the logic you want to implement.

Comment: Please cite your documentation source that told you that the angled brackets and forward slashes are valid syntax.

Answer (score 1):

The obvious assumption is that the markup code is incorrect.  But you might have a preprocessor that removes it.

If the markup is code is correct, then under some circumstances, the logic would be:

```
WHERE AND . . .
```

And that is incorrect.  A typical approach to this would be:

```
WHERE 1 = 1 AND
    <if test="gNumber != null">
        dph.GNUMBER = #{gNumber} AND
    </if>
    <if test="licence != null">
        dph.dlicenceNumber = #{licence} AND
    </if>
       dph.REASON = (CASE WHEN dph.REASON IS NOT NULL THEN par.CODE END)
```

The `CASE` expression itself would not be causing an error.  But then again, it is not necessary either, because `NULL` values fail comparisons anyway.  So this is equivalent:

```
WHERE 1 = 1 AND
    <if test="gNumber != null">
        dph.GNUMBER = #{gNumber} AND
    </if>
    <if test="licence != null">
        dph.dlicenceNumber = #{licence} AND
    </if>
       dph.REASON = par.CODE
```